# emberjs star/unstar items just in the memory

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I build a basic emberjs app, the app lists posts, and every post has a star / unstar event.
I would like to list all starred posts in the sidebar, without server side communications. What is the best way to do that? My first idea is that: I create a star action to PostsController, which add starred posts to an array, and I will list this array in the template.

Comment: if you don't want to persist it how will users who come into a hard link or the app at another date/time see the stars? or is it ok that each time they enter the app the stars are not set?

Comment: it is ok, I don't want to save the changes, this is an experiment, I'm just looking for solutions that I implement later to my other projects

Comment: in that case -@Adrien's reply below will get you rolling

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think for this is to set an attribute `star` on the post model which will be `false` by default, then you can set `star` to `true` when you want and render in the sidebar all post filtered by star attribute.

Code would be something like this (coffeescript) :

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend
  title: DS.attr('string')
  star: false

App.Post.reopenClass
  stared: ->
    @filter (post) -> post.get('star') is true
```

From this you can render `App.Post.stared()` array in your sidebar.

Comment: It will prints just the function: function () { return this.filter(function(post) { return post.get('star') === true; }); }

Comment: Updated my answer, you have to call the function, ie: display `App.post.stared()`

Comment: I tried this too, I only got an empty array, I also tried different statements

Comment: Did you set the `star` property of some `post` to `true` ? If so, they should be in the returned array.

Comment: Yes, and I also tried with false, I got this Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID' error

Comment: I'm not sure why this happen, I would think there is something else somewhere in your code.. :s